# Missing "improve edit" and "reject and edit" button in review queue

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

The "improve edit" and "reject and edit" buttons were missing on [a particular question I was reviewing today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6811367). Is this a bug, or are these options not available for certain edits? If not, why?

[image]

Comment: It's a freehand circle, not a *fried*hand circle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the post had since been deleted by the author while the suggested edit was still active.

Review items don't get immediately invalidated when a post gets deleted - it takes a little bit of time. So it is possible to still review a suggested edit after the post's deletion. However, the system when deciding to show the item to you **does know** that the post is deleted, and thus you don't have the privilege to edit it (via the improve features) and decides not to show those buttons to you.

Comment: Ah, I began to suspect that it might be something like that just after I asked the question. I'll accept in ten minutes.

Comment: That's curious. I mean, dropping the item (at least until the post is undeleted) would be ok, ignoring the delete is also understandable, but arbitrarily remove half the options for handling it? Sounds broken, at least by design.

Comment: @Deduplicator It doesn't usually take that long for review to get invalidated. I imagine the fact that the OP deleted, then undeleted, then deleted again had something to do with the odd delay. But removing the buttons is still a good thing. It's sort of a fallback - if something weird happens, at least don't give them things they can't actually do.

Comment: What happens if the edit is approved?