# Suggested edit review without "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" options

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits I generally see 5 options <kbd>Approve</kbd>, <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>, <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>, <kbd>Reject</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd> like below

[image: suggested edit with 5 options]

But today in one of the edits I was reviewing I just saw 3 options <kbd>Approve</kbd>, <kbd>Reject</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd>. I clicked <kbd>Skip</kbd> as it looked odd. When will I see such an review?

[image: suggested edit with 3 options]

Comment: I could be wrong, but it may have been a tag wiki edit. Since you don't have the rep to edit it yourself, the review system may not even give you the option. (Just a guess. I'm sure someone who can actually review edits and has for a while could say for sure.)

Comment: I actually found another possible answer to this question [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284226/missing-improve-edit-button-in-review-queue) Unfortunately, without seeing the review in question, it's hard to say whether the question was deleted or not, and I've been unable to find anything else on this either here or on MSE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two possibilities. One is that the post that is the subject of the edit has since been deleted; you can't initiate further edits to a deleted post (with a few exceptions*).

The other is that you don't have 20k and it's a tag wiki (excerpt) suggestion.

I've observed and verified both of these on various occasions (not necessarily on SO); I'm not aware of any other possibilities.

---

<sub>**Exceptions:*</sub>

- <sub>*You're a ♦ mod*</sub>
- <sub>*You're the owner of the post — but if so, you can't edit if it's a question and you deleted it yourself*</sub>
- <sub>*You have 10k tools (2k tools on betas) and can see all deleted posts, provided you can find them*</sub>

Comment: Well, nice to know I was right on tag wiki being a potential cause.

Comment: Note that you need 5k rep to be able to approve/reject tag wiki edits

Comment: Yeah... just had a quick look - the OP came across a suggested edit to a question that hadn't long been deleted.